# Rewriterule - urls dont change in the browser bar

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It's very strange to me, but:

I have a website with `guestbook-add.php`. I want to show it to the visitors as `gasterbuch.html`.

So I have written in `.htaccess` (my real domain has been changed in that listing to `http://mywebsite.com/` of course):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://mywebsite.com/index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^gasterbuch.html$ http://mywebsite.com/guestbook-list.php
    RewriteRule ^eintrag-hinzufugen.html$ http://mywebsite.com/guestbook-add.php
</IfModule>
```

Now, when I type in the browser `http://mywebsite.com/gasterbuch.html`, I see the text generated by `guestbook-add.php` (which is fine).

**But in the browser url bar**, I see `http://mywebsite.com/guestbook-add.php` instead of `http://mywebsite.com/gasterbuch.html` (like it was the 302 redirect).

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://mywebsite.com/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^gasterbuch.html$ http://mywebsite.com/guestbook-list.php
RewriteRule ^eintrag-hinzufugen.html$ http://mywebsite.com/guestbook-add.php
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^gasterbuch.html$ /guestbook-list.php [L]
RewriteRule ^eintrag-hinzufugen.html$ /guestbook-add.php [L]
```

should work.

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark it as correct so other users who have the same problem as you, will know how you solved it.

Comment: Yes, just marked and up-voted - I could not mark it from start (time limit before you can mark it).